# MySQL query to Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm trying get the best performance for an Elasticsearch query.
I need something similar to this MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_a IN ('value1', 'value2') AND field_b = value
```

The number of values for `field_a` may be between 1 and let's say 20.
All fields require an exact match.

Right now I'm using query:

```
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                 { "term" : {"field_a" : "value1"}}, 
                 { "term" : {"field_a" : "value2"}} 
              ],
              "must" : {
                 "term" : {"field_b" : "value"} 
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The index has at this point around 30 million documents and this query returns the result in 0.04s - 0.06s (via cURL).
Is there a better way to get the results I need?

**Update**
The field_a is a string not analyzed.
The field_b is an integer.

Comment: Is the value of `field_a` is numeric? if so, you can use the `gt` and `lt` operators for a wide range check.

Comment: Do you really need a constant score block? You are anyway using filter block, so scoring would not matter for you

Comment: @AvihooMamka `field_a` is not numeric.

Comment: @shiladitya The query is created from an example posted on Elasticsearch official site.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of values you want `field_a` to compare against, you can use the following query:

```
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                 { "terms" : {"field_a" : ["value1", "value2", "etc..."]}} 
              ],
              "must" : {
                 "term" : {"field_b" : "value"} 
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this. It's not improving the performance, but it's easier to read. I'm gonna use it.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes must be created for field_a and field_b. Do not use * in query - it reduces performance. Instead * -  write the fields you need.